# von neumann stability for the simple one way wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$u_t$ = $mu_x$. I believe that it is conditionally stable for the forward time backward space discretization($\frac{u^{n+1}_{j} - u^{n}_{j}}{\Delta t}$) on the left and $m\frac{u^{n}_{j} - u^{n}_{j-1}}{\Delta x}$, because if using von Neumann analysis $u = \beta^ne^{iq j}$, I set modulus of $\beta < 1$. I calculated it to be the CFL condition but I am not sure if that is correct.
Now I add some notation. This question is doing a numerical scheme with the pde. $t^0$ < $t^n$ < T and $x_0 < x_n$ < $x_L$, where $x_{n+1} = x_{n} + \Delta x$. The numerical scheme is that $u_j^{n+1}$ is the $u$ with time $t^{n+1}$ and $x_j$. The idea is that time t is divided into equally sized intervals and the length of each time interval is $\Delta t$ and length of each displacement interval is $\Delta x$. $u_t$ is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$, $u_x$ is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, and m is a constant.

Comment: I am not sure if it should be conditionally stable. I calculated it but not sure if my calculation is correct. I believe it is stable if the CFL condition holds

Comment: I don't think most people with vN-algebra knowledge know your notation/definitions. You should clarify something if it is non-standard (in this case, everything! what is u_t? what is m, what is u_x, what are these $\Delta$'s, what is n,j, q and what is $\beta$?).